# NHibernate doesn't map query result to its type

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I was wondering if it possible to retrieve the pure result of the query and not its mapped result. keeping in mind that my entity type is only know at runtime.

```
var session = _sessionProvider.GetSession();
return session.QueryOver<object>(type.FullName).List()
```

This query will return a list mapped to its concrete type. But i would like to retrieve an `IEnumerable<object[]>` which contains for example `[0] { Id : 1, RoleId : 1, Name : "Name" }`.

Comment: I have used the solution suggested by @MichaC in combination with reflection and so on.But since i didn't want NHibernate to create proxys for the complex properties. I used the  `Projections.SqlProjection()` syntax and i was able to select only the 'pure' values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to transform something into something. I expect that you know at least the column names you want to have in your output.

You could do this for example by using the PassThrough result transformer and define the projections with `Projections.Property("<colName>")`

```
object alias = null;
var result = session.QueryOver<object>(type.FullName)
    .SelectList(list => list
       .Select(Projections.Id())
       .Select(Projections.Property("RoleId"))
       .Select(Projections.Property("Name")))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.PassThrough)
    .List<object[]>();
```

If you do not know the properties you could query your `type` with reflection of what not...